# Random unresolved reference error while executing gradle task

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I'm having some trouble while trying to execute `./gradlew bootRun` on a spring-boot application.

The bizarre thing is that executing the main class through IntelliJ, everything runs perfectly. But when I try to execute via gradle task, I get the `Unresolved reference: Polygon` error. The file which occurs the unresolver reference is:

```
import self.project.polydator.Polygon

interface PolygonResolver {
    fun resolveShape(sides: List<Int>): Polygon
}
```

The failed task is `:usecase:compileKotlin`.
I'm using gradle `4.8.1`.

I have already tried to executed `./gradlew clean` before `./gradlew bootRun`.

- EDIT1: I tried to run `gradle bootRun` instead of using the gradle wrapper. My installed gradle version is `4.8`.
- EDIT2: I'm using MACOS X

I would really appreciate any help! 
Thanks!

Comment: What Os are you using? I'd recommend you install gradle https://gradle.org/

Comment: So you can execute gradle clean and gradle bootRun without ./gradlew... install on Linux OS.. I think you are using because ./gradlew is being called

Comment: I'm currently using MasOS X.

Comment: I tried to run the task through the gradle installed on my machine, but the error persists.

Comment: you can try with gradle clean build

Comment: after gradle bootRun

Comment: I tried both, `gradle clean build` and `gradle bootRun` D:

Comment: does it work? @Chih

Comment: No, it does not :(

Comment: I wanted to run it xD could you share you repo? or something like that?